# Saving File correctly in android google chrome

Tags: html

i am trying to save data using a anchor tag in a offline mobile website.
My download attribute works fine (saves the file with the correct name i.e. with Date ) in chrome desktop but when run on android device in chrome It saved as csv;base64

can anyne suggest me any way  where in i can save it correctly.

Comment: exportLink.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;base64,' + window.btoa(result));
 exportLink.setAttribute('id', 'rollno');
 exportLink.setAttribute('download', 'Survey_Answer_'+Date+'.csv');

Comment: my results have data to be saved